# What is radius vector? Is it a zero vector?

Tags: vector-analysis

I only know radius vector is the position vector of any point $(x,y,z)$ in space with respect to origin which in vector notation takes the form $x\vec{i}+y\vec{j}+z\vec{k}$,where $\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}$ are unit vectors along the axes $X$,$Y$ and $Z$ respectively. Is my concept correct? If it is correct then origin can also be treated as a radius vector. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes and yes for both

Comment: Please click the green tick mark beside my answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.Both your thinkings are correct.